# php within x seconds of y time

Tags: php

How can I make a script that can check wether it is currently x seconds from 12am or 12pm?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have to get the current timestamp, using the `time()` function.

Then, you have to get the timestamp of 12am, using for example the `strtotime()` function.

Then, substract those two values ; and if the absolute value of the result is `X`, then it's the right time for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $noon = strtotime( "noon" );
    $midnight = strtotime( "midnight" );

    $timeToMidnight = $midnight - date();
    $timeToNoon = $noon - time();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime)
{

// convert to unix timestamps
$firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
$lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

// perform subtraction to get the difference (in seconds) between times
$timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

// return the difference
return $timeDiff;
}

//Usage :
echo timeDiff("2002-04-16 10:00:00","2002-03-16 18:56:32");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$time = time();
if( (date("g", $time) % 12) * 3600
    + preg_replace('/^0/', '', date("i", $time)) * 60
    + preg_replace('/^0/', '', date("s", $time))
    > $selected_time) {

    // do whatever

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work... right?

$time = time();
if ((date("g", $time) == 12) && (date("i", $time) < 10)) {echo 'W00T!';}